# Indexer library installation error in python

Tags: python-3.x, indexer

I am trying to install indexer library in python but getting the following error.[image]

Comment: Post this command and console output as text, please

Comment: found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with the same problem and solved it by upgrading setuptools before installing indexer.

Upgraded setuptools by running following command:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Then install indexer:

```
pip install indexer
```

Comment: nope did not work. did you try this on python 2? if so then the actual issue is indexer failing for python 3